# Transpose a database table to dynamic column count result

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, transpose

There are several transposing questions on Stackoverflow, but looking at few non of them is really similar to my problem. The main difference being: the have a predefined set of columns.

Let's say my table looks like this:

```
ID Name   Value
---------------
1  Set    Mitch
2  Get    Jane
3  Push   Dave
4  Pull   Mike
5  Dummy  John
...
```

I'd like to transpose it to become:

```
Set    Get   Push  Pull  Dummy ...
----------------------------------
Mitch  Jane  Dave  Mike  John  ...
```

Comment: Is there just one row to transpose? If there are multiple rows, how do they relate (i.e. is there a second row with `Name = 'Set'`, and how does it relate to the others)?

Comment: @Tomalek: Each row transposes to a separate column. No rows in original table are related in any way shape or form. So basically remove IDs and transpose the whole table. That's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for a "dynamic pivot table". See the example here, or Google that term for more information:

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx

Comment: Your link provided sufficient information about `PIVOT` operator, but examples were a bit more complicated so I only gave you a +1 and accepted a different answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to do this in the SQL?  It seems pretty trivial if you can just do it after you get a SELECT * query into an array you can manipulate at will.